# Asp.Net Web Api - attribute for not binding/formatting a parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a method on an ApiController that looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> GetSlideSets() {
        IServiceClass serviceClass = new ServiceClass();
        //...
```

Yes, I am aware that this is not good design but I'm addressing this issue in a different iteration.

At a certain point in my application I need to call this functionality from within the project itself so I thought I could simply reuse the controller (and why not, I can pluck it out of my IoC container). The only problem is that in this case, I need to inject my own implementation of `IServiceClass`, easy enough:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> GetSlideSets(IServiceClass serviceClass = null) {
        serviceClass = serviceClass ?? new ServiceClass();
        //...
```

Except now I am getting errors when calling this via a regular Api call `Optionalparameter 'serviceClass' is not supported by FormatterParameterBinding`.

I know that there are various attributes that control bindings. Is there one that I can put on the parameter to say it shouldn't bind.

Comment: Can you move the `serviceClass` to the scope of the controller instead of the action method scope where you have it now?

Comment: IoC happens at object construction usually, thus the IServiceClass parameter would need to be a constructor parameter (that you copy to a private instance field and use from there) and not a method parameter.  I.e., what he said.

Comment: That would mean that ServiceClass initializes for any controller method call. In a better architecture this wouldn't be a problem, but this is a prototype gone live and things like routing and controller refactoring are for another iteration. @ChrisF - you're right, this part of it is just regular DI, not IoC, I'm just injecting a dependency via parameter. I could also inject it via a property which would achieve a similar result but I'm looking specifically for the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, it's probably a better idea to inject the dependency in the constructor.

But if you really must avoid binding an action parameter, there isn't a built-in attribute but you can create one pretty easily. Here's what it could look like:

```
public class DontBindAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return new DontBindParameterBinding(parameter);
    }

    private class DontBindParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
    {
        public DontBindParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter) : base(parameter)
        {
        }

        public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            actionContext.ActionArguments.Add(Descriptor.ParameterName, Descriptor.DefaultValue);
            var completedTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            completedTaskSource.SetResult(null);
            return completedTaskSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to apply the attribute to the parameter afterwards:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> GetSlideSets([DontBind] IServiceClass serviceClass = null)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just going with making it `Lazy<>` and using property injection in this case, but thanks for showing me how to do it.